# moving unique_ptr in c++

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I'm designing a class that has to get ownership of a unique_ptr and do sth with it. Here is a minimized version of the code:

Chunk.h:

```
class Chunk {
public:
    Chunk(std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> contents);
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> contents;
};
```

Chunk.cpp:

```
Chunk::Chunk(std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> content): 
             contents(std::move(content)){ }
```

but it couldn't compiled though to this error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<char []>::unique_ptr(std::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<unsigned char []>&>::type)’
```

Comment: Why are you using a `<unsigned char[]>` template as argument and `<char[]>` template as member?

Comment: Surely the argument should be a non-const reference to a `unique_ptr`, or an rvalue reference(&&)?

Comment: @Aracthor oh no! It's about 3 hours that Im checking it and i don't notice this silly mistake!

Comment: @MartinBonner [It works without reference as well](http://ideone.com/eBOOLZ)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a `<unsigned char[]>` template as argument and `<char[]>` template as member.

They are not even considered as the same class at all by the compiler. Use exactly the same type if you plan to use template functions like `std::move` with it.